# A black hole in windows 10 applications when second monitor connected

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop

When having connected to second monitor with my laptop HP 255 G7 and Windows 10 I have sometimes a glitch, where sometimes in different applications I have a hole. It's like a hole because I can there and I will got to the application that is behind the current application with a hole. But the hole is always black. It happens in different situations and in diffent applications. Like random. The problem only happens and exists when the second monitor is connected. When reconnecting the HDMI cable the problem fixes. But it second monitor is connected it will happen sooner or later again. Hole always happens at the top of the screen with height about 10-20%. It always happens on the main laptop screen, not the second monitor.

I attach 2 images. First is the application with a hole - in this example it happened in adobe reader (the content is obfuscated, but the app and hole can be seen).

The second attachement is my laptop basic info.

[image: a black hole in the adobe reader at the top that can be cliked to get to the application that is behind the current application with the hole]

[image: my laptop basic info]

Comment: Please add to your post the models of the two monitors, how they are connected to the computer, and what model are your computer's display adapter and its driver.

Comment: I know of a glitch with Adobe Reader or Chrome where this sometimes happen, but only if the application is maximized. If you select the app, and press WIN+arrow down, you unmaximize that app. If this is the problem, the black bar will go away and the problem is gone until you maximize it again. I have never figured out the cause, but it went away by itself after a month and I've seen it happen and go away to 5 different people now